# what is this regex expression doing here

Tags: perl

```
for $file ( $ftp -> ls() )
    {
        $bar = file;                

        $dst_dir     =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;     #so this is replacing \$\& with $src
        $dst_pattern =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;

        $dst_dir1 = eval( $dst_dir );
        $dst_file = eval( $dst_pattern ); 
    }
```

In Perl, what is this doing to the filename `$bar`.  so `$bar` is replacing `\$\&` but what is that?  Also what would evaluate on a string give here

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it replaces every occurrence of '$&' with '$bar' in `$foo`. This is a typical way to implement a simple place-holder token syntax in data.

The value returned by `eval` is the result of treating the value of `$foo` as if it were Perl source code. Assuming normal execution, `eval` will return the last expression evaluated in `$foo` (or the argument of a `return` statement if one is executed). Note that evaluating `$foo` may also have side effects (I/O, variable assignments, etc.). It's impossible to say more without knowing what's in `$foo` to start with.

Comment: but what is $& there is no $_ before this so it's not referencing the above

Comment: `$&` is just literal text in `$foo`, which is being replaced.

Comment: @LukeMakk - Because of the backslashes in the regex, the `$&` isn't being treated as a Perl special variable, but simply as a character sequence. `$_` is irrelevant to what's going on here (except, perhaps, for what might be in `$foo`).

Comment: well theres the entire code snippet, its looking at every file in a directory returned by a ftp connection.  what is $& character sequence here? I'm pretty confused

Comment: @LukeMakk - It's still unclear what's going on because it depends on what's in `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern`. Also, are you sure that `$bar = file;` is right? It looks like it should be `$bar = $file;`. If you forced me to guess, I'd say all this is just a weird way of interpolating the file name in place of each `$&` character sequence in `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern`.  By the way, the comment `#so this is replacing \$\& with $src` is wrong--it should be `...with '$bar'`, not `...with $src`. It's also weird that `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern` are not restored each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you a comprehensive answer since we don't know the superior aim of the code where the snippet is embedded. Especially with respect of what is in `$foo` and `$bar`.

Nevertheless I wrote a little script that illustrates the specific substitution and the following `eval` statement:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

$bar = "10";
$foo = '10*$&';

print 'content of `$bar`: ', $bar, "\n";
print 'content of `$foo` befor substitution: "', $foo, "\"\n";

$foo =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;

print 'content of `$foo` after substitution: "', $foo, "\"\n";

$a = eval($foo);

print 'result of the evaluation: ', $a, "\n";
```

The script's output is:

```
content of `$bar`: 10
content of `$foo` befor substitution: "10*$&"
content of `$foo` after substitution: "10*$bar"
result of the evaluation: 100
```

The closing `eval` statement evaluates the content of `$foo` namely `"10*$bar"` as if it were a regular perl expression. Thus you can think of the line

```
$a = eval($foo);
```

as

```
$a = 10*$bar;
```

Thus the value `100` is stored in `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed...

```
for $file ( $ftp -> ls() )
{
    $bar = file;
```

This should be `$bar = $file` and not `$bar = file` (your script is missing leading `$` in `file`). Otherwise, you're just putting the string `file` into `$bar`.

The other part of your expression is:

```
$dst_dir     =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;     #so this is replacing \$\& with $src
$dst_pattern =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;
```

What is the value of `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern`? That's the ***real*** question here.

Somewhere `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern` is being set. This is where you substitute the file in your FTP into these strings. I then notice this:

```
$dst_dir1 = eval( $dst_dir );
$dst_file = eval( $dst_pattern );
```

It appears that `$dst_dir` and `$dst_file` are some sort of commands? Why else use `eval` being run on them? What are the values of these two strings? Why run them via `eval`?

What's going on is that these two commands have the string `$&` in them, and you're substituting the file you're ftp'ing for that string.

Let's assume `$dst_dir` is equal to `$ftp->get("$&")`. The file name you get from your `$ftp->ls` command (let's assume it's `bar.txt` is substituted into that string. Thus, `$dst_dir1` is set to `$ftp->get("bar.txt");`.

And looking at the whole loop:

```
for $file ( $ftp -> ls() )
{
    $bar = file;                

    $dst_dir     =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;     #so this is replacing \$\& with $src
    $dst_pattern =~ s/\$\&/\$bar/g;

    $dst_dir1 = eval( $dst_dir );
    $dst_file = eval( $dst_pattern ); 
}
```

I see another issue. You're looping through each file and replacing `$&` in `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern` each time. However, if you're doing this for every file, and you're not resetting the original values of `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern`. That means the second time you go through your loop, you're not changing `$dst_dir` and `$dst_pattern`. And, so with all of the other times you go through your loop too.

You are also not checking to make sure the substitution actually worked, and you're not checking to see if `eval` worked by checking the value of `$@`.

On top of that, you're not setting `use strict;` and probably not `use warnings;`.

Here's a new version of the loop:

```
for my $file ( $ftp->ls ) {
    my $dist_dir     = $dst_dir;      # Make sure you don't futz with your
    my $dist_pattern = $dst_pattern;  # original templates!

    # Check to make sure replacements work!
    if ( not $dist_dir =~ s/\$\&/\$file/g ) {
       die qq(Couldn't put file name "$file" into "$dist_dir");
    }
    if ( not $dist_pattern =~ s/\$\&/\$file/g ) {
       die qq(Couldn't put file name "$file" into "$dist_pattern");
    }

    # Check for Eval!
    my $dst_dir1;
    my $dst_file1;
    $dst_dir1 = eval( $dist_dir );
    if ( "$@" ) {
       die qq(Evaluation of `$dist_dir` failed!: $@ );
    }

    $dst_file1 = eval( $dist_pattern );
    if ( "$@" ) {
      die qq(Evaluation of '$dist_pattern' failed!: $@);
    }
}
```

This is checking to make sure the substitution works, and is also saving not modifying your template each time.

Comment: Note that the original code escapes the `$` in the substitution--it's `s/\$\&/\$bar/g`. You're substituting `$file` instead of `\$file`, so I doubt very much that following up with an `eval` is correct.